# How to parse a list of words according to a simplified grammar?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, lisp, nlp

Just to clarify, this isn't homework. I've been asked for help on this and am unable to do it, so it turned into a personal quest to solve it.

Imagine you have a grammar for an English sentence like this:

```
S => NP VP | VP
NP => N | Det N | Det Adj N
VB => V | V NP
N => i you bus cake bear
V => hug love destroy am
Det => a the
Adj => pink stylish
```

I've searched for several hours and really am out of ideas. 
I found articles talking about shallow parsing, depth-first backtracking and related things, and while I'm familiar with most of them, I still can't apply them to this problem. I tagged Lisp and Haskell because those are the languages I plan to implement this in, but I don't mind if you use other languages in your replies.

I'd appreciate hints, good articles and everything in general.

Comment: Look into **Parsec** library in Haskell. I believe you'll find all you need there.

Comment: I know about Parsec, but I'm challenging myself to write a parser. I didn't specify that clearly I think.

Comment: I still don't get, what you are looking for. If you need a tool to create particular parser implementing your grammar, then Parsec is your good friend. If you are wanna to create a general-purpose parser library from scratch, then your example with particular grammar confusing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working Haskell example. It turns out there's a few tricks to learn before you can make it work! The zeroth thing to do is boilerplate: turn off the dreaded monomorphism restriction, import some libraries, and define some functions that aren't in the libraries (but should be):

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Control.Applicative ((<*))
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

ensure p x = guard (p x) >> return x
singleToken t = tokenPrim id (\pos _ _ -> incSourceColumn pos 1) (ensure (==t))
anyOf xs = choice (map singleToken xs)
```

Now that the zeroth thing is done... first, we define a data type for our abstract syntax trees. We can just follow the shape of the grammar here. However, to make it more convenient, I've factored a few of the grammar's rules; in particular, the two rules

```
NP => N | Det N | Det Adj N
VB => V | V NP
```

are more conveniently written this way when it comes to actually writing a parser:

```
NP => N | Det (Adj | empty) N
VB => V (NP | empty)
```

Any good book on parsing will have a chapter on why this kind of factoring is a good idea. So, the AST type:

```
data Sentence
    = Complex NounPhrase VerbPhrase
    | Simple VerbPhrase
data NounPhrase
    = Short Noun
    | Long Article (Maybe Adjective) Noun
data VerbPhrase
    = VerbPhrase Verb (Maybe NounPhrase)
type Noun      = String
type Verb      = String
type Article   = String
type Adjective = String
```

Then we can make our parser. This one follows the (factored) grammar even more closely! The one wrinkle here is that we always want our parser to consume an entire sentence, so we have to explicitly ask for it to do that by demanding an "eof" -- or end of "file".

```
s   = (liftM2 Complex np vp <|> liftM Simple vp) <* eof
np  = liftM Short n <|> liftM3 Long det (optionMaybe adj) n
vp  = liftM2 VerbPhrase v (optionMaybe np)
n   = anyOf ["i", "you", "bus", "cake", "bear"]
v   = anyOf ["hug", "love", "destroy", "am"]
det = anyOf ["a", "the"]
adj = anyOf ["pink", "stylish"]
```

The last piece is the tokenizer. For this simple application, we'll just tokenize based on whitespace, so the built-in `words` function works just fine. Let's try it out! Load the whole file in ghci:

```
*Main> parse s "stdin" (words "i love the pink cake")
Right (Complex (Short "i") (VerbPhrase "love" (Just (Long "the" (Just "pink") "cake"))))
*Main> parse s "stdin" (words "i love pink cake")
Left "stdin" (line 1, column 3):
unexpected "pink"
expecting end of input
```

Here, `Right` indicates a successful parse, and `Left` indicates an error. The "column" number reported in the error is actually the word number where the error occurred, due to the way we're computing source positions in `singleToken`.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. While I intentionally don't want to use Parsec as it would spoil the challenge for me, I do appreciate your time and it does help me a lot :)

Comment: @Ben Actually, implementing parsec yourself isn't too hard! I recommend giving it a try. =) Peek at the definition of the main top-level Parser type, then go from there.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different approaches for syntactic parsing using a Context-free grammar.

If you want to implement this yourself you could start by familiarizing yourself with parsing algorithms: you can have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Types_of_parser) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Parsing), or if you prefer something on paper the chapter on Syntactic Parsing in [Jurafsky&Martin](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~martin/slp.html#Chapter13) might be a good start.

I know that it is not too difficult to implement a simple syntactic parser in the Prolog programming language. Just google for 'prolog shift reduce parser' or 'prolog scan predict parser'. I don't know Haskell or Lisp, but there might be similarities to prolog, so maybe you can get some ideas from there.

If you don't have to implement the complete parser on your own I'd have a look at the Python NLTK which offers tools for CFG-Parsing. There is a chapter about this in the [NLTK book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch08.html#sec-context-free-grammar).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are a number of algorithms that you could use. Below are some popular dynamic programming algorithms:
1) CKY algorithm: The grammar should be in CNF form
2) Earley algorithm
3) Chart parsing.

Please google to find the implemenation of these. Basically, given a sentence, these algorithms allow you to assign a context free tree to it.

Answer (score 0):

You provided example of non propabalistic grammar. So you can use tools ANTLR, JFlex, Scala Parser Combinators, Parsers python library to implement parser by this grammar in very similar code as you provided.

Comment: The point is not that the grammar is not probabilistic, but that it is deterministic. So parser generators for artificial languages would work, but they'd break down as soon as non-determinism is introduced.

Comment: In that case it will just return first parse, and it correct since you haven't provided any scoring for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem for you might be that the way you'd parse a computer language is a lot different than the way you'd parse natural language.

Computer languages are designed to be unambiguous and relatively easily to get the exact meaning of from a computer.

Natural languages evolved to be compact and expressive and usually understood by people.  You might manage to make deterministic parsing that compilers use work for some very simple subset of English grammar, but it's nothing like what is used to parse real natural language.